# Delete self while running

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, uninstallation

Im currently creating a uninstallation application which deletes the application folder. The problem is that i cant delete the uninstaller application which is in the same folder cause its running.
Is there a way to delete the application while running, so its just in the memory.

```
        string Installation = UninstallRegister.Read("InstallationLocation");
        if (Directory.Exists(StartMenu))
        {
            Directory.Delete(StartMenu, true);
        }
```

Best regards

Comment: possible duplicate of [Executing and then Deleting a DLL in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179466/executing-and-then-deleting-a-dll-in-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple idea would be to copy the uninstall application to %TEMP% and run from there. This would however leave a file in %TEMP% (which would probably not be noticed by anyone).

Comment: The temp folder can also be cleaned up using Windows cleaning utilitiese when required too, so using the TEMP directory is a good way to go.

Comment: It works well except for some reason i get a error in the uninstaller that the application which extracts the uninstaller to temp is still running.

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@tempPath + "uninstall.exe");
            return;

Answer (score 0):

You can use command prompt Del command

[nircmd](http://nircmd.nirsoft.net/cmdwait.html) has a command named cmdwait
you can set a wait time to delete your file then close the application and let it delete

Comment: This wont work for me, cause the EXE needs to be deleted or moved from the application folder before closed, else the application folder cant be deleted. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command. It close your app and start cmd remove directory command arter deley=3000

This solution remove app and **folder**.

```
Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/C ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 3000 > Nul & RD /s /q " + Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath));
                    Application.Exit();
```