# Delete application executable on exit

Tags: vb.net

So I am trying to get my application to delete itself on exit.

I am currently using this ([found here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31454/How-To-Make-Your-Application-Delete-Itself-Immedia)):

```
Process.Start("cmd.exe", 
"/C choice /C Y /N /D Y /T 3 & Del " + Application.ExecutablePath);
Application.Exit();
```

The CMD window comes up, but will not remove the application. Any ideas why not?

EDIT:
So it works sometimes... other times it does not... ideas?

Comment: Did you try the option that uses `ping` with a `-w` parameter to introduce a delay?

Comment: Does the application sometimes take more than 3 seconds to fully close?

Comment: @JeffBridgman I tried that also, same issue

Comment: @mellamokb upped it to 10 seconds to make sure. And same thing

Comment: This question may be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/q/179466/945456

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you cannot delete an application while it's running.
You could introduce some delay in the cmd command(I don't know how), or you could simply make another application with a timer set on 5 sec. And insert the code:

```
System.IO.File.Delete(Application.ExecutablePath)
Me.Close
```

Then just use the Process.Start("your/Delete/App/Path.exe") in the first app.

Comment: That is pretty much exactly what I ended up doing. Thanks for your response!